# How to get simple JSON object in Retrofit 2.0.0 beta 1?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to convert this simple response that looks like this

```
{
  "field_one": "bearer",
  "field_two": "fgh",
  "field_three": 0
}
```

I am using latest version of Retrofit 2.0.0-beta1. I never used Retrofit before. There are many tutorials and example of old version of Retrofit. I tried different techniques that works with older versions but thats not working with latest one. Due to lack of documentation of latest version of Retrofit I could not find solution.

I want to use latest version.

Here is POJO

```
public class Auth {
    @SerializedName("field_one")
    @Expose
    private String fieldOne;

    @SerializedName("field_two")
    @Expose
    private String fieldTwo;

    @SerializedName("field_three")
    @Expose
    private Integer fieldThree;

    // setter and getter etc. etc. 
}
```

Here is Interface that I am using

```
interface Authorization {
   @Headers("Authorization: This is some header")
   @GET("api/v1/mytoken")
   Call<Auth> getToken();
}
```

This is the way I am calling service

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://myendpoint.com/")
            .client(client)
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Authorization serviceAuthorization = retrofit.create(Authorization.class);
    serviceAuthorization.getToken().enqueue(new Callback<Auth>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Auth> response) {
            Log.d("Response", ">>> "+ response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("fail", ">>> "+ t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I am unable to get output. It just print this

```
Response: >>> retrofit.Response@2567e2c3
```

I want to get data in Auth Object that I will use later.

Please suggest me best solution

Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having? Do you get a compiler message? A runtime error?

Comment: No no error comes. I updated question what I get output and what I want

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are not seeing you are expecting to see your object printed out on this line --

```
Log.d("Response", ">>> "+ response.toString());
```

That is going to call the `toString` method on the response.  If you want to call it on your deserialized object, call the [`body()`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Response.html#body--) method first --

```
if(response.isSuccess()) {
    Log.d("Response", ">>> "+ response.body().toString());
} else {
    Log.d("Response", "Error - " + response.code())
}
```

Comment: Using **response.toStirng()** I am getting `Response: >>> retrofit.Response@2567e2c3` but when I use **response.body().toString()** I am getting **NullPointerException**

Comment: I also tried **response.raw().toString()** now I am getting this **Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=https://myendpoint.com/api/v1/oauth2/token}**

Comment: That helps -- 404 is that not found, so you are not calling the correct endpoint.

Comment: Yeah, something is wrong with your call causing you to get a 404.  See my edit to avoid to NPE.  You can also call `errorBody()` on the response if you want the text of the error response, but it is likely just some variation of "not found"

Comment: I am giving _Headers_ as in documentaion in [link] (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) . I also tried to give headers in _Intercepter_. but same 404 response